# Dar nombres a las curvas de un gráfico matplolib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Tengo un diccionario de dataframe y me gustaria puestar los keys del diccionario como etiquetas de las curvas

```
df_inflation_usa = quandl.get('RATEINF/INFLATION_USA', start_date='2000-12-31', end_date='2021-05-13')
df_inflation_gbr = quandl.get('RATEINF/INFLATION_GBR', start_date='2000-12-31', end_date='2021-05-13')
df_inflation_ita = quandl.get('RATEINF/INFLATION_ITA', start_date='2000-12-31', end_date='2021-05-13')
df_inflation_fra = quandl.get('RATEINF/INFLATION_FRA', start_date='2000-12-31', end_date='2021-05-13')
df_inflation_deu = quandl.get('RATEINF/INFLATION_DEU', start_date='2000-12-31', end_date='2021-05-13')
df_inflation_jpn = quandl.get('RATEINF/INFLATION_JPN', start_date='2000-12-31', end_date='2021-05-13')
df_inflation_aus = quandl.get('RATEINF/INFLATION_AUS', start_date='2000-12-31', end_date='2021-05-13')
dict_of_dfs = {"usa": df_inflation_usa,"gbr": df_inflation_gbr,"ita": df_inflation_ita, "fra": df_inflation_fra, "deu": df_inflation_deu,"jpn": df_inflation_jpn,"aus": df_inflation_aus}
```

Entonces intenté:

```
fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(12, 8))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for BAR in dict_of_dfs.keys():
    dict_of_dfs[BAR].plot(ax=ax, label=BAR)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No es relacionada pero cualquier sea el tamano que doy simpere esta el mismo tamano

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear una lista con los nombres que deseas en cada curva... y después cambias la linea que sigue al for, en la parte de label, debes poner, la lista de nombres, así: ***label=str(Nombres[i])***

Por ejemplo:

```
Nombres = [None,
          8,
          (30, 8),
          [16, 24, 30],
          [0, -1],
          slice(100, 200, 3),
          0.1]

i = 0
for BAR in dict_of_dfs.keys():
    dict_of_dfs[BAR].plot(ax=ax, label=str(Nombres[i]))
    i += 1
```

**Tu código, debería quedar así:**

```
# Tantos nombres como gráficas tengas
Nombres = [None,
           8,
           (30, 8),
           [16, 24, 30],
           [0, -1],
           slice(100, 200, 3),
           0.1]

fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(12, 8))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

i = 0
for BAR in dict_of_dfs.keys():
    dict_of_dfs[BAR].plot(ax=ax, label=str(Nombres[i]))
    i += 1
```